# User course listings with contact forms

Tags: nodes, webforms, panels, emails

I'm very new to drupal and trying to get my head around how things are setup.

I'm attempting to create a training course listings website where a user can join as a course provider and add listings for upcoming courses. I have this ability sorted but, I'm struggling to find a way for visitors to fill in a contact form attached to the course listing node, which will go into an admin panel for the main administrator. Once approved by the admin an email alert will be sent to the listing's author/course provider and they can go into their own panel to view the message with a link to the course where it was submitted. I have played around with webforms, panels but as far as I can tell all messages get attached to the form and not the node itself. Hope this makes sense :)

If you know of any guides, tutorials on this type of setup or if you could advice in any way that would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - asking for guides and tutorials is off-topic here.  If I was to attempt this, I would first try something like this:

- create a content type with the relevant fields you want a prospective user to fill out
- create a hidden field that includes the email address of the course provider
- include another "hidden" field using the Field Permissions module something along the lines of "approved" so that only Admin can access or view this field. This would be a boolean type field
- create a custom View visible only to Admin that shows ONLY that content type, filtered by those where the approved field is false

The Admin can then go through each item, check and set the 'approved' field to true if appropriate

- Create a Rule, based on that content being saved that checks the value of the approved field - if it has changed and is now true, send an email using the hidden email field to the course provider

It's pretty involved, but should work.

[Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

[Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

> You need Views if
>
> You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it
>   differently. You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you
>   want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically. You use
>   /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type. You
>   like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles
>   the way you like. You want a way to display a block with the 5 most
>   recent posts of some particular type. You want to provide 'unread
>   forum posts'. You want a monthly archive similar to the typical
>   Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the
>   form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month,
>   and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
>   for that month. Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some
>   of the obvious uses of Views.

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

Comment: thanks Geoff you have given me a great head start and a lot to digest, will keep me busy for a while :) and from now on I'll be more specific with any additional questions, thanks for the heads up.